# Why onChange of react-form-hooks not working in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

//below code gives an  Error:'onChange is not a function' .
I rendering the TextInput and it's dynamic means I am creating dynamic form using react-hook-form but the onChange is not working.please help!

```
   <Controller
    control={control}
    name={fields.field_name[index]}
    rules={{ required: true }}
    render={({ onChange, value }) => (
        <TextInput
            placeholder={' ' + fieldName}
            editable={fields.context_type == 'Location' ? false : true}
            keyboardType={fields.context_type == 'Decimal' ? 'decimal-pad' : 'default'}
            value={fields.context_type == 'Location' ? machineLocation : value}
            onChangeText={(value) => onChange(value)}
        ></TextInput>

    )}
/>
```

Comment: What's `Controller` ?

Comment: I think you need `field: { onChange }` as your render props

Answer (score 0):

You need to call render function as

```
render = {(fields:{onChange,value}) => {
}
```

In the latest version of react-hook form this change was implemented